# Is there a way to change FlowDirection only for a specific Grid RowDefinition in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I have an existing UI design and i would like to add RTL support with minimal changes in existing XAMLs. Currently, most screens are 3x3 Grids of the following form:

row 0:  [ **Title** - 2 columns ]  [ **Quit** - 1 column ]

row 1:  [          **Content** - 3 column            ]

row 2:  [ **Back** - 1 column ] [ empty ] [ **Next** - 1 ]

I would like to add RTL support only for Row 0 and Row 2. Is that possible? I couldn't find FlowDirection property for it. I dont mind overriding the Grid control and implementing this myself i just couldn't find how... Any ideas?